# I want to plot each legend next to my each plot in the loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have 4 files: I13A, I13B, I13C and I13D 
In each file I have two columns with data (x and y)
They look this way:

[... 4.016746160 600.0
4.050238473 617.0
4.083730786 578.0
4.117223099 562.0
4.150715412 604.0
4.184207724 526.0
4.217700037 589.0
4.251192350 548.0
4.284684663 581.0
4.318176976 580.0
4.351669289 577.0
4.385161602 549.0
4.418653915 565.0 ...]

I will like to write a legend next to each plot as I show you in the last picture attached.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
import glob
import re


def sorted_nicely( l ):
    """ Sorts the given iterable in the way that is expected.

    Required arguments:
    l -- The iterable to be sorted.

    """
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key)]
    return sorted(l, key = alphanum_key)

#How to plot x-ray files
fnames_rayosx = glob.glob("I13*.xy")
fnames_rayosx_sort = sorted_nicely(fnames_rayosx)

for idx,f in enumerate(fnames_rayosx_sort):
    fname = print(f)
    data_rayos = np.genfromtxt(fname= f, delimiter=' ', usecols=range(2))

    x = data_rayos[:,0]
    y = data_rayos[:,1] + idx*9000

    plt.xlabel("2\u03F4 (\u00B0)")
    plt.ylabel("Intensity (arb. units)")
    plt.xlim(5, 40)

    plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

I would like to obtain something like this:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to have a look [at this documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/text_intro.html)

Comment: Thank you! I dit it with that documentation really fast. Very useful.